# java.text.DecimalFormat blank when zero?

Tags: java, formatting

Is it possible to show blank (empty string) when the number is zero (0)? (strict no zeros at left)

Comment: With which method? There are tons of methods that format strings in DecimalFormat

Comment: Is the number any `java.lang.Number` or a specific subclass?

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar Any method, let me know if any method would do.
@trashgod It is a java.lang.Number but I could use a specific subclass if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to use [`MessageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), specifically its [`ChoiceFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html) feature:

```
double[] nums = {
    -876.123, -0.1, 0, +.5, 100, 123.45678,
};
for (double num : nums) {
    System.out.println(
        num + " " +
        MessageFormat.format(
            "{0,choice,-1#negative|0#zero|0<{0,number,'#,#0.000'}}", num
        )
    );
}
```

This prints:

```
-876.123 negative
-0.1 negative
0.0 zero
0.5 0.500
100.0 1,00.000
123.45678 1,23.457
```

Note that `MessageFormat` does use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) under the hood. From [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
FORMAT TYPE:       number
FORMAT STYLE:      subformatPattern
SUBFORMAT CREATED: new DecimalFormat(
                      subformatPattern,
                      DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(getLocale())
                   )
```

So this *does* use a `DecimalFormat`, albeit indirectly. If this, for some reason, is forbidden, then you must resort to checking for a special condition yourself, since `DecimalFormat` does not distinguish zero. From [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> `DecimalFormat` patterns have the following syntax:
>
> ```
>  Pattern:
>          PositivePattern
>          PositivePattern ; NegativePattern
> ```

There is no option to provide a special pattern for zero, so there is no `DecimalFormat` pattern that can do this for you. You can either have, say, an `if`-check, or just let `MessageFormat/ChoiceFormat` do it for you as shown above.

Comment: I really need to use java.text.DecimalFormat

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format method:

```
int num1=0;
int num2=33;
string str1 = (num1!=0) ? String.format("%3d", num1) : "   ";
string str2 = (num2!=0) ? String.format("%3d", num2) : "   ";

System.out.println("("+str1+")");  // output: (   )
System.out.println("("+str2+")");  // output: ( 33)
```

syntax of format is very similar to c printf (for this basic use)

Comment: Er, that will print 0 as "  0", not as an empty string.

Comment: You're right, this answer was intended for a different question...
I'll make some changes to fit this one as well :)